# cygwin C++ static/portable library to avoid releasing source code?

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, portability

I have some code which I can compile and run on a Windows machine using cygwin. The code is natively Linux and compiled with g++ in cygwin.

In that code, there are several libraries that I would like to redistribute without releasing the source code. Is it possible to create portable object files that can be moved to another Windows machine with cygwin installed and be able to successfully link to them?

Comment: since you have edited this, i think that you are doing this in the wrong way, considering http://www.cygwin.com/ i suggest to have a look at the **Cygwin is not** section.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [MinGW project](http://mingw.org/) which is a port of the GCC suite ( and other tools ) for Windows.

Just use the MinGW package without Cygwin if you need a compiler and/or gcc under Windows.

Comment: Err, why? Cygwin is perfectly capable of linking those libraries, it's all that MinGW is and more.

Comment: MinGW is not useful for me, my code is natively Linux and needs to be compiled with g++

Comment: MinGW is portable between several machines with just a copy and paste and can do what is required. Also i don't think that compiling with Cygwin under Windows is a good way of doing this because Windows and Cygwin are 2 different environment, as far as i know there is no IDE under Windows that use Cygwin, all the free IDE uses MinGW.

Comment: @user788171 g++ is available in MinGW, i don't get your requirements at this point, if you are looking for a GCC version under Windows that is easy to transfer to other machines MinGW is the way.

Comment: @user827992: If the asker has Linux-native code that they want to use on Windows without a heavy porting effort, by far the easiest option is using Cygwin. That provides access on Windows to functions and features that are normally Linux-only.

Answer (score 1):

If your code links against the Cygwin DLL (which it will do if you build it using g++ in Cygwin), your code is affected by the GPL. If you distribute the binaries then **regardless of whether or not you distribute any part of Cygwin yourself** you are obliged to also distribute the source code.

When you build code that links against GPL code, that linked code is also forced under the GPL. Like it or not, that's rather the point behind the GPL.

You have two options for distributing your binaries without being obliged to make the source available under the GPL:

- Remove the dependency on Cygwin, by rewriting your code to not require the Linux-style APIs that Cygwin provides.
- [Buy a Cygwin licence from Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/). That will give you the right to link against a Cygwin DLL, and to distribute all the binaries, without being obligated to release your source code under the GPL.

**Edit**: I also refer you to [my answer to a related question on the Cygwin GPL licence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292801/220155).